# Magento 1.7 Index Managment is always stuck at Catalog URL Rewrites could this be affect Cross Selling and Related Products

Tags: magento

Hello I am trying to set some products for cross selling and related products. When I go into the admin section for the products and select cross sell products do not show up for me to select. I would like to be able to assign some products. I read that you should reindex which I have done but the Catalog URL rewrites always shows as processing from day one. I have 14k products.

Comment: there must be some error while reindexing, can you find the error and share plz, you find the error in var folder in magento root file named would be expection.php. be sure that your log and exception are enabled from admin panel.

Comment: Fixed the issue with "Reset Filter" as suggested. The reindex issue still exist, there is no expection.php in my var folder.

Comment: magento/var/log/(exception.log|system.log)

Comment: you have to enable logs in magento admin -> developer section. but your problem might be due to insufficient memory

Comment: Looks like I have alot of errors. The website will not allow me to paste the errors from the log.

Answer (score 0):

This will not solve your index management issue however in regards to cross selling, when you first hit the cross selling tab there will often be 'no records found', until you hit the 'Reset Filter' button. This gets me some times!